# Selecting a ROI manually in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to select a user-defined area and fill with 1s, preferably with mouse input. Any suggestion how? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
roipoly
```

does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the *Image Processing Toolbox* to use `roipoly` as Georg suggested.

If you don't have that, you could try creating a rubber band box using

```
rbbox
```

There's a good example in the help. You might need to fiddle with units depending on how you're displaying your data. Remember to click and hold, drag and release..

Answer (score 0):

> h=impoly;

This code helps you to select a closed polygon of the image.