# Matlab imcrop with specific mask

Tags: matlab, crop

Is it possibile in Matlab, to create a specific mask (which is not a rectangular/square) for the imcrop command?
I need to exclude boundaries from an image, but they are irregular, so I need to make like a crop mask.

Thanks

Comment: You may want [`imfreehand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfreehand.html)

Comment: what are you expecting to get from this cropping? a rectangular image or a vector of pixel values? see [`poly2mask`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying the image using `imshow`, then just use the command

```
roipoly
```

and you should be able to define irregular boundaries.

See [Selecting a ROI manually in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529236/selecting-a-roi-manually-in-matlab/13529399#13529399)

Comment: imcrop seems that it doesn't permit to define irregular boundaries, but just regula shape like rectangular. I'd like to define an irregular shape, like T or L.